# what do you call a guy that treats people differently in his or her own interests

Tags: word-request

A guy may annoy a good-tempered person many times，but when he or she comes to a person that is colder and smarter, they tend to treat them with more respect. Sometimes they treat others nicely when they are in need of them. They just treat others in a way they want to, according to the person's social status, characteristics, importance and influence.

What do you call this kind of person? Snobby, diplomatic or something else？

Comment: Your question is hard to understand because it begins with a confusing run-on sentence. You should also [do some research yourself and mention that in the question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (For example, did you put "snobby" and "diplomatic" into a thesaurus and check out some related words?)

Comment: i‘ve done some research as well but found nothing good.

Comment: What did your research find?

Comment: find what you can find please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *diplomatic* is not a good fit. It implies that a person is careful not to offend other people, and you have said that this guy annoys people.

The word *snobby* might fit. A snob (snobby person) is polite or welcoming to people they think are important, and rude or dismissive to people they think are unimportant. But that does not necessarily mean that he or she is acting "in his or her own interests". First, a snob might be acting that way out of habit, instead of doing it as a deliberate strategy to get what they want. Second, many snobs see themselves as part of the "important" group, so they may already have what they want.

Here are some other suggestions that might fit:

- A *flatterer* is a person who gives other people lots of fake praise because they want they other people to do them favors.
- A weak or unimportant person who tries very hard to earn the favor of stronger or more important people is a *sycophant*, *toady*, *bootlicker*, *brownnoser*, or *ass-kisser*.
- A person who only cares about themselves, and does not care about other people, is a *narcissist*. We could also call them *egocentric*, *self-centered*, *self-absorbed*, *self-serving*, or simply *selfish*.
- A person who keeps convincing other people to give them things, while giving nothing in return themselves, is a *leech*, *sponge*, *mooch*, *freeloader*, *parasite* or *user*.

Almost all of these words are insults, and a few of them (e.g. *brownnoser* and *ass-kisser*) are rather crude. So be careful how you use them.